# SQL join for selecting two records with common data

Tags: sql

I have database with this type of records:

```
Id     | Value  | DocId |
------ | ------ | ------|
1      |  10    |  null |
2      | -10    |  1    |  //this is child of record with id = 1
3      |  15    |  null |
4      | -15    |  3    |  //this is child of record with id = 3
5      |  7     |  null |
6      | -7     |  5    |  //this is child of record with id = 5 
7      | 16     |  null |
```

So I want to select the records where `Id = 1` and `Id = DocId`, so this should return (because those are the records with `Id = 1` and `DocId = 1`)

```
Id     | Value  | DocId |
------ | ------ | ------|
1      | 10     |  null |
2      | -10    |  1    |
```

I know I can use a where clause but I need to do it with Join.

Comment: Add some more rows of sample data, and also specify the expected result as formatted text.

Comment: The query looks fine. You should get a row with six columns (three from the first record, three from the second). Don't you?

Comment: More details on the use case would also be helpful.  What does id represent, what is the relationship between id and docId?  What is the real world information you are looking for (i.e. what is the business requirement).

Comment: You said that should return `Id`, `Name`, `DocId`, but in you sample data is no Name column at all.

Comment: With SQL questions you should always also tag your DBMS. Which are you using? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? ...

Comment: Wait, are you trying to show the records for ID 1, but only if there exists a record with this docid? (But well, as this phrase already suggests, you still wouldn't join, but use `EXISTS` for this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select twice from the same table as if they were two separate tables:

select * from TheTable t1, TheTable t2 where t1.id = t2.DocId;

Answer (score 0):

You are showing a result for `where id = 1 or docid = 1`. So why must you use a join instead? This doesn't seem to make sense. Anyway, here you go:

```
select t.*
from t
join (select 1 as id) x on x.id in (t.id, t.docid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you want the records where the id = 1 or the docId = 1.  So in sql you can say almost exactly that:

```
select * from my_table where id = 1 or docId = 1;
```

Comment: The OP wrote "I know I can use a where clause but I need to do it with Join."

Comment: Why do you need to complicate this with a join?

Comment: Yeah, I wonder :-) However, it seems the OP *does* know how to solve this with a where clause, but for some strange reason needs a solution with a join instead.